# Put scroll bars inside the element

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div which have scroll bars, but, when scroll appears it is outside the element (see image below). I want to put the scroll inside the red area. Is it possible? How?

I have not tried nothing, because I don't know how to start this or can't find a similar issue.

[image]

Comment: You should post relevant code, otherwise it's just guessing. Try using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Trufa it is only a question I have a long time, without codes, but happens when I have horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any html or CSS way to go about moving the scroll bars to appear inside the div because scrollbars are created by the browser rather than the code itself. The best bet might be using some javascript to make your own scrollable area and then positioning it how you like. Look up how to create scrollbars and scrollable divs with jQuery. Good Luck!